# How to create a bar plot that considers 2 variables years and months on the x axis and that considers 2 variables on the y axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a data frame called 'm' with 4 columns and about 100 rows.

How can I create a bar plot where I get the right chronological order on the x-axis with months 1-12 repeating for every year?

Comment: can you `dput()` the 'm' data frame?

Comment: Idk, what does the dput command do?

Comment: you need to [create a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  it makes it much easier for users to help you.

Answer (score 0):

**Update on OP's request (see comments):**

1. I have used `make_date` from `lubridate` package to mutate a new column `date`. This time date is class date -> day is set to first of month:
2. With `pivot_longer` we bring the data in correct shape to plot our bars.
3. Then we use `scale_x_date` to show every 4 month.

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
m1 <- m %>% 
  mutate(date = make_date(YEAR, MONTH)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = c(AUTO, IMP),
    names_to = "names",
    values_to = "values"
  )
  
ggplot(m1, aes(x=date, y=values, fill=names)) +
  geom_bar(position='dodge', stat='identity') +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "4 months" , date_labels = "%b-%y")+
  theme_bw()
```

Output:
[image]

**Original answer:**
We create a character column `Date`. To be a date we would need a day, therefore we leave it as character class.
With `sprintf()` we put the two columns `YEAR` and `MONTH` together:

```
library(ggplot2)
m$Date <- with(m, sprintf("%d-%02d", YEAR, MONTH))

ggplot(m, aes(fill=AUTO, y=IMP, x=Date)) +
  geom_bar(position='dodge', stat='identity')
```

data:

```
m <- structure(list(YEAR = c(2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 
2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2009, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 
2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2010, 2011), MONTH = c(1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 1), AUTO = c(0, 0.003130344, 0.01565172, 0.338077161, 
0.01565172, 0, 0, 0.003130344, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.012277821, 0.021486187, 
0.009208366, 0.009208366, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), IMP = c(0, 
0, 0.037564129, 0.062606882, 0.006260688, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0.006138911, 0, 0.003069455, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -25L), spec = structure(list(
cols = list(YEAR = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), MONTH = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), AUTO = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), IMP = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that already comes close to what I want. Is there a command to make it possible that the x axis is only labelled on every 4th month? And how can I have bars for both IMP and AUTO? I assume I would have to write sth. else than "dodge" for that.

Comment: The downvote definitely didn't come from me! Last question (probably): How can I get the "Mar", "Jul" parts away? So that I just have 3, 7, 11,... (the values of the column MONTH) on the y-axis instead.

Answer (score -1):

```
set.seed(1)
m <- data.frame(year = rep(2019:2021,each=12), 
                month = rep(1:12,3),
                AUTO = rnorm(36,30,1),
                IMP = rnorm(36,20,4)
                )

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

m %>%
  mutate(date = as.Date(paste0(year,"-",month,"-01"))) %>%
  pivot_longer(IMP:AUTO,"group","value") %>%
  ggplot(., aes(fill=group, y=value, x=date)) +
  geom_bar(position='dodge', stat='identity')
```